# How to post file from my dropbox account to another dropbox account in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, dropbox-api

I want to send image from my dropbox account to another dropbox account through ios app.I can send image my account by using following code.

```
[[self restClient] uploadFile:@"image.png" toPath:dir withParentRev:nil fromPath:filePath];
```

Please tell me how i post to another account dropbox via ios app?

Comment: You mean, you would ask for authorization to post to that other account? Can you be a bit more specific and add more info?

Answer (score 0):

Uploading to another Dropbox account in the iOS Core SDK would use the same code you posted, with the only difference being the `restClient` would have been initialized with a different session/user, via one of the following:

```
- (id)initWithSession:(DBSession*)session;
- (id)initWithSession:(DBSession *)session userId:(NSString *)userId;
```

To connect to both to use `uploadFile` in a client-side app like this would mean exposing credentials (an access token) in the app for your account though, which is inadvisable.

Instead, to copy a file from your account to the end user's account in a client-side app like this, you should use the copy reference feature:

Use this once to create the copy reference from the originating (that is, your) account:

```
- (void)createCopyRef:(NSString *)path; // Used to copy between Dropboxes
```

Use this in the end-user app to copy the file specified by the copy reference into the end-user's account:

```
- (void)copyFromRef:(NSString*)copyRef toPath:(NSString *)toPath; // Takes copy ref created by above call
```